# Creating common controller functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, angularjs-service

How do I create some sort of utils bundle that would be accessible from all my controllers?

I have this route code in my main module:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('lpConnect', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/home', {template: 'views/home.html', controller: HomeCtrl}).
        when('/admin', {template: 'views/admin.html', controller: AdminCtrl}).
        when('/connect', {template: 'views/fb_connect.html', controller: MainAppCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/connect'});
}]);
```

I want a function that can be common to `HomeCtrl`, `AdminCtrl` and `MainAppCtrl`.

How should I do it in AngularJS?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The way to define common code in angular is through Services.

You would define a new service like so :

```
.factory('CommonCode', function ($window) {
        var root = {};
        root.show = function(msg){
            $window.alert(msg);
        };
        return root;
    });
```

In your controller you would inject this service..like so

```
function MainAppCtrl($scope,CommonCode)
{
     $scope.alerter = CommonCode;
     $scope.alerter.show("Hello World");
}
```

Just include CommonCode as an argument to your controller function.. Angular will take care of injecting it for you ( Read on Dependancy Injection ..to understand what is happening here. )

Comment: Anyone else find it.... odd that you define a service by calling the factory method? Seems like some naming improvements would go a long way to increasing approachability of the framework.

Comment: @bclinkinbeard exactly my thoughts as I'm wrapping my head around AngularJS. `factory()`, `value()`, `constant()`, and `service()` seem to be no more than shortcuts for specific cases of `provide()`, which is intended to be used for defining (providing) services. I guess the docs would benefit from a pull request that puts the above sentence in large letters somewhere.

Comment: To be frank, when I first started this is what confused me. Factory() generally returns a singleton, as you can see, from the above example. A service() - returns a constructor. A value() and constant() as far as I can tell generally do the same thing. And all these are wrapper ( convenience ) over provide()...

Comment: Is the $window variable essential here?

Comment: It decouples your code from the global `window` object. So its much easier to test ( mock! ) .

Comment: can you set state of the service in each controller (instead of config at module level)

Comment: e.g. i need to pass a $scope to the service, so that i dont have to pass in each function

Answer (score 9):

Just to update previous answer (which only define what `factory` is), there are 3 ways to [inject dependencies](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) (define common code) in AngularJS:

- Providers
- Factories
- Services

I will not talk much about provider because it is a more laborious method for dependency injection. However, [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) explains very well how they work.

---

Technically, **service** and **factory** are used for the same thing.
It turns out, a service is a constructor function whereas a factory is not.

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory):

```
module.service( 'serviceName', function );
```

> When declaring `serviceName` as an injectable argument you will be
>   provided with **an instance of the function**.

```
module.factory( 'factoryName', function );
```

> When declaring `factoryName` as an injectable argument you will be
>   provided with **the value that is returned by invoking the function**
>   reference passed to module.factory.

---

You can use the one you prefer and obtain the **same result**.

Here is two codes doing exactly the same thing through [**`service`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) first, and then **`factory`**:

**Service syntax**

```
app.service('MyService', function () {
  this.sayHello = function () {
    console.log('hello');
  };
});
```

**Factory syntax**

```
app.factory('MyService', function () {
  return {
    sayHello: function () {
      console.log('hello');
    }
  }
});
```