# use angular factory to hold a value for rest of application to access to minimize server calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, factory, angular-promise

I have the following factory:

```
angularModule
  .factory('ArticleCategoryService', function ($http, $q) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    var categories = [];

    var _getCategories = $http.get('/api/articles/category').success(function (_categories) {
      categories = _categories;
    });
    // .error( function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // });

    // Public API here
    return {
      getCategories: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        deferred.resolve(_getCategories);
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
  });
```

and this is the section that calls this service in the controller:

```
// Calls the getCategories function from the ArticleCategory Service,
    // Will return a promise
    ArticleCategoryService.getCategories()
      .then(function (categoriesResult) {
        $scope.categories = categoriesResult.data;
      }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

This works but there will be a GET call to the server every time user comes back to this view/state and the `categories` object that belongs to the factory is never used.

I'm trying to make it so that it will return the `categories` variable in the factory singleton, and have it initialize on site load (or from first GET call).

But if I just return `categories` when user calls `getCategories`, it will return nothing since we need time for the `$http` call.

Comment: there is no reason for the `$q.defer()` in your code, since `$http` already returns a promise.  aside from that, factories aren't singletons.  If your goal is to call a function multiple times but only have it make a server call once, then you should use a service, and in the service, check for data existence, then make your factory call if the data doesn't exist yet.

Comment: I will agree with you that $http returns a promise so $q.defer() not needed unless you're using it in the case of @mouse-reeve's answer, but all providers are singletons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18939709/when-to-use-service-instead-of-factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `categories` is defined, and resolve the promise with the variable rather than the `GET` request if it is:

```
return {
    getCategories: function () {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (categories.length > 0) {
            deferred.resolve(categories);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(_getCategories);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

Comment: There's a bit of a type mismatch here. `_getCategories` returns an object and I have to access the data with `_getCategories.data`, but in the first conditional, it just returns an array. Is there a cleaner way to handle this aside from checking the type?

Comment: You should resolve this in the service, not in the controller by either setting `categories` to a value that reflects what the promise returns, or having the service return a value that looks like what you set in `categories`. 

I think you can, in the `_getCategories` function, set `categories` they way you currently are, and then `return categories` - but you will have to check if that works.

Comment: the promise is returned to the controller before the $http call triggers, and then when it's resolved, what the controller gets is the return from the $http call. I tried to just return `categories` but doesn't work. My resolve is in the service, as it currently is, just with your answer placed in and returning `categories`

Comment: Nevermind, it ended up working when I replaced the .success with .then. I guess it's because .success is a chain on the callback and returns the promise, but .then actually returns the results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing exactly same thing on my app. I have a main module and a main controller within it that wraps any other controllers, so its scope is persistent over views.

In this main controller you could assign the factory's getCategory() data to a scope variable and then you could use that in your entire app, because the scope will be inherited to child scopes.

```
angularMainModule
  .factory('ArticleCategoryService', function ($http) {
      var ArticleCategoryServiceMethods = {};

      //fn: getCategories
      ArticleCategoryServiceMethods.getCategories = function(fromWhere){
         return $http.get(fromWhere)
                 .then(function(res){
                     return res.data;
                 }, function(err){
                     return err.status;
                });
      }

      return ArticleCategoryServiceMethods;
}

angularMainModule
   .controller('MAINCTRL', function($scope, ArticleCategoryService) {

    //get all categories
    $scope.categories = ArticleCategoryService.getCategories('/api/articles/category');

   //... the rest of the main ctrl code ... //

}
```

... when you define the main module, make sure you inject the rest of your modules in it

```
var angularMainModule = angular.module('angularMainModule', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngAnimate',
    //< ng - etc >,
    'Module1',
    'Module2',
    //< module - n >
]);
```

...and the markup (i'm bootstrapping my angular app manually, but you could add the `ng-app="angularMainModule"` attribute on the html tag if you're doing it that way):

```
<html ng-controller="MAINCTRL">
<!-- head data -->
<body>
<div id="page" ng-view></div>
```

If you want to make sure data is loaded before your app opens the main page, you could add that service call in the `routeProvider` block of your app (on the default route), so when the MAINCTRL will be loaded the data will be already there, ready to be assigned.

Comment: Where is the routeProvider?

Comment: In the config block of main module, is where you define your app routes.

Answer (score -1):

```
angularModule
  .factory('ArticleCategoryService', function ($http) {
    // Service logic
    // ...

    var categories = [];

    $http.get('/api/articles/category').success(function (_categories) {
      categories = _categories;
    });


    // Public API here
    return {
      categories: categories
    };
  });


angularModule
   .controller('ControllerMain', function($scope, ArticleCategoryService) {

       $scope.categories = ArticleCategoryService.categories;

    });
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I believe you're returning a new object using with the value of `categories` at the time it's run, which would be before the $http call returns. I just tried this out and it didn't work.