# Reuse functions with $scope acces Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, code-reuse

I'am sloving problem of reusing same function with scope access in two Controllers
decribed here:
[How to include/inject functions which use $scope into a controller in angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642138/how-to-include-inject-functions-which-use-scope-into-a-controller-in-angularjs)

In controller:

```
new CommonService($scope).getSomethingFromDB();
```

In factory:

```
services.factory("CommonService", function (DBService) {

function Factory ($scope) {

    this.$scope = $scope;
}

Factory.prototype.getSomethingFromDB = function () {
    if( angular.isUndefined(this.$scope.vrsteObracuna) || this.$scope.vrsteObracuna === null) {

        this.$scope.loading = true;
        DBService.getSomethingFromDB(
            function success(data) {
                this.$scope.loading = false; //ERROR !!!
                this.$scope.vrsteObracuna = data;
            },
            function error(data, status, headers, config) {
                this.$scope.loading = false;
                etna.notifications.error("Error fetching!");
            }
        )
    }

    return this.$scope.vrsteObracuna;
}

return Factory;
});
```

Problem is that after success callback from DBService.getSomethingFromDB
this.$scope.loading is undefined ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't $scope into "success" closure, try to use this code:

```
services.factory("CommonService", function (DBService) {

function Factory ($scope) {

    this.$scope = $scope;
}

Factory.prototype.getSomethingFromDB = function () {
    if( angular.isUndefined(this.$scope.vrsteObracuna) || this.$scope.vrsteObracuna === null) {

        this.$scope.loading = true;
        var that = this;
        DBService.getSomethingFromDB(
            function success(data) {
                that.$scope.loading = false; //ERROR !!!
                that.$scope.vrsteObracuna = data;
            },
            function error(data, status, headers, config) {
                that.$scope.loading = false;
                etna.notifications.error("Error fetching!");
            }
        )
    }

    return this.$scope.vrsteObracuna;
}

return Factory;
});
```

Comment: Every closure in javascript has self "this" object (scope). You can use other "this" object (scope) in closure by variable "that" (or other variable name).