# angularjs service confusion

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below element is within my mainController

```
<img src="loader.gif" ng-hide="done_ajax"/>
```

and I can't alter using $scope.done_ajax because my ajax is done in another controller. How can I communicate between mainController and my controller2?

```
app.service('finished_request', function(){

});

callAPI("getUser", {
            method: "GET"
        }).done(function (resp) {

            $scope.$apply(function () {

            });

});
```

Comment: have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446755/on-and-broadcast-in-angular

Comment: @A.T. I prefer service than using $rootscope.

Comment: try this.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324202/creating-common-controller-functions

hope it helps.

Comment: @RafaelK it's confusing, can you explain mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to share data between two controllers, you can use **Service**. Service are singletons, so you can easily share your data.

However, you want to notify when you have changed your data, so to achieve this, you should use the `$broadcast()` and `$on()` method.

- `$broadcast` : dispatches the event downwards to all child scopes

As there is no parent-child relation between your scopes, if your controllers are at the same level, you can inject `$rootScope` into the controller and broadcast the event to all child scopes.

**EDIT**

there is example by using **Service** and **broadcast** parameter.

So you can do :

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, $rootScope, Service) {

  $scope.data = 1;

  $scope.set = function(n){
    $scope.data = n;
    Service.set($scope.data);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('set', $scope.data);
  }

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();




(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  $scope.$on('set', function(e, data){
    $scope.data2 = Service.get();
    $scope.data3 = data;
  });

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller);

})();
```

**Service**

```
(function(){

  function Service(){

    var data;

    function get(){
      return data;
    }

    function set(value){
      data = value;
    }


    return {
      get: get,
      set: set
    };

  }

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Service', Service);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app'>

    <h3>Controller 1</h3>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <button ng-click="set(data)">change</button>
      <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    </div>

    <h3>Controller 2</h3>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
      <p>Data from controller 1 : {{data2}}</p>
      <p>Data from controller 1 without service : {{data3}}</p>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Now, you will be able to communicate between differents controllers, and retrieve data by using Service.

You can see the [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eCPY6s2sEuG1HSlnKWYU?p=preview)

**Just by using Service singleton**

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {

  $scope.data = 1;

  $scope.set = function(n){
    Service.set(n)
  }

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();



(function(){

function Controller($scope, Service) {
  //Retrieve service instance
  $scope.data_service = Service;

}

angular
.module('app')
.controller('ctrl2', Controller);

})();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app'>

    <h3>Controller 1</h3>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <button ng-click="set(data)">change</button>
      <input type="text" ng-model="data">
    </div>

    <h3>Controller 2</h3>
    <div ng-controller="ctrl2">
      <p>Data from controller 1 : {{data_service.get()}}</p>
    </div>

  </body>
```

Here, we just share the instance of our Service.

You can see the [**Plunker with Service**](http://plnkr.co/edit/gvaPZ82VJCclLPrcCbJq?p=preview)

Comment: it's also possible to use broadcast without a service. Correct?

Comment: yes, you can pass data as second parameter of `$broadcast` method.

Comment: Can do u it without $broadcast? take a look my flow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312018/angularjs-service-doesnt-work-in-my-case

Comment: @AliceXu I've update the code and the plunker, now you can see two example, by using broadcast without parameter and Service, and just broadcast with parameter.

Comment: I'm following someone's tutorial with just using service, any I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @AliceXu  Ok, i've update the code, with what you want, just by using Service instance.

Comment: Why you don't use like app.service('service_name',function(){}); ?

Comment: This is a habit. By wrapping your Angular module in an anonymous function, you prevent your code from conflicting with other code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312018/angularjs-service-doesnt-work-in-my-case/32312203?noredirect=1#comment52500416_32312203

look at here, why would he use $watch and you don't?

Comment: This is the power of Service. I just wrap my service instance into the `$scope` of my second controller, and this is the same instance, services are singletons. So when i retrieve data from service in my view, you don't have to use `$watch`, because we are sharing instance, not just a variable

Comment: Good aproach but if u have multiple service your code look abit messy I think. Do you think I should use factory instead of service in this case?

Comment: In your case it's not really important. In my example, you can use `Service` instead of `Factory`. In this case, it is not really important because they are all Singletons. Basically, function that you write in `Service` will be new-ed, while the function will be invoked in a `Factory`.

Comment: singleton means what? can u explain why factory isn't a singleton?

Comment: Singleton means that there is **only one** instance of a given object. And i said that all angular Service are singleton