# angularjs service doesn't work in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below is an element is within my mainController

```
<img src="loader.gif" ng-hide="done_ajax"/>
```

and my js look like this

```
//service
    app.service('request_service', function(){
        this.finished = false;
    });

//main ctonroller
    app.controller('mainController', ['$scope','request_service', function($scope,request_service){
            $scope.ajaxed = request_service.finished;
    }]);

// second controller
app.controller('secondController', ['$scope','request_service', function($scope,request_service){

    callAPI("getUser", {
                method: "GET"
            }).success(function (resp) {

                $scope.$apply(function () {
                 request_service.finished = true;
           });

    });
```

What's wrong is my usage of angularjs service? I want to hide a loader that controlled by the mainController, by passing the conditional value when the ajax call is done in my second controller.

Comment: create a plunker plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You request a value of your service and you do not watch it for changes. Therefore it will most likely (depending on the sequence and time your controllers are initialized) be false and remain false.

```
$scope.ajaxed = request_service.finished;
```

If you want to know when the request_service.finished changes, it should be [watched](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#methods):

```
$scope.isFinished = aService.isFinished;

$scope.$watch(function() { return aService.isFinished; }, function(newV, oldV) {
    $scope.isFinished = newV;
});
```

Comment: why there's param in the $watch callback? can't I just set $scope.ajaxed = false? but either with that it doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: It's a listener function defined in the docs, you can click on the link I supplied to read up on the $watch method. Yes, it should be in your main controller.

Comment: strange it doesn't work still, anything wrong for my service? and my second controller?

Comment: when I console.log(newVal, oldVal) it return undefined.

Comment: Here is a [small](http://plnkr.co/edit/v1YcqvYExih3vOIDSbZC?p=preview) example how to use `$watch`. This should get you on your way.

Comment: my eyes is so painful, why don't u use $scope? @@

Comment: why have to use so many functions? can't I set in the service this.finished = true?

Comment: I don't really use $scope a lot. I changed it to work with $scope in the plunker.

Comment: I'd modified your code to a more simple version, http://plnkr.co/edit/OpPptw3qH5zs4wYGPrSf?p=preview but there's a problem with it, can you tell me what's wrong there?

Comment: I think you should change your `$watch` variable into `$scope.$watch(function(){ return request_service.finished} ...`. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r0L62zy8/)

Comment: @themyth92 is correct on why your simplified version isn't working. (Updated the plunker and answer to use a service value).

Comment: COOL! but my mind is totally blown. Why it needed to be return in the $watch?

Comment: If you use a string in the first parameter of $watch, this string will get evaluated as expression against the current `$scope`.   Bearing that in mind: $scope.aservice = aService;
  $scope.isFinished = aService.isFinished;
  $scope.$watch("aservice.isFinished", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    $scope.isFinished = newVal;
  }); would also work.