# How to pass data between different modules using service having two different controller with different modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services, angular-controller

What I am doing here is, I have created one service to share the data between controller but the problem is both the controller is having a different modules. so my doubt here is, how can i make communication between two different controllers having different modules.

Here is my service
**login.service.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.pages.auth.login')
        .factory('dataService', dataService);

    /** @ngInject */
    function dataService(){

        var sendarr = [];

        var addData = function(newObj) {
            sendarr.push(newObj);
        };

         var getData = function(){
            return sendarr;
        };

        return {
            addData: addData,
            getData: getData
        };

    }

})();
```

First controller **login.controller.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.pages.auth.login')
        .controller('LoginController', LoginController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function LoginController(msApi,$state,dataService)
    {
        // Data
        var vm = this;

        vm.login = login;
        vm.startApp = startApp;
        vm.fbLogin = fbLogin;
        var auth2;
        // Methods
        function fbLogin(){
            FB.login(function(response){
                if(response.status=='connected'){
                    testAPI();
                }
                else if(response.status == 'not_authorized'){
                    console.log('error');
                }
                else{
                    console.log('please log in');
                }
            });
        }

        function testAPI() {
            console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
            FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);

            });
        }

        function startApp(){
            gapi.load('auth2', function(){
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
                auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: '990822731291-21sdd22ujqc78l1q2i2lmf5hfe5satj1.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
                fetch_basic_profile: 'true',
                // Request scopes in addition to 'profile' and 'email'
                //scope: 'additional_scope'
                });
                attachSignin(document.getElementById('customGoogleBtn'));
             });
        }

        function attachSignin(element) {
            auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
                function(googleUser) {
                    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
                    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
                    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
                    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());
                    var pushData = [profile.getId(), profile.getName(), profile.getEmail()];
                    console.log(pushData);
                    dataService.addData(pushData);
                    $state.go('app.pages_auth_verify-mobile')
                }, 
                function(error) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            });
        }

        function login(){
            var jsonData = {"mobile":vm.form.mobile};
            msApi.request('login.credentials@save',jsonData,
                // SUCCESS
                function (response)
                {
                   console.log(response.error);
                    if(response.error == 1){
                        vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = true;
                    }
                    if(response.error == 0){
                        vm.form.mobileErrorFlag = false;
                    }
                },
                // ERROR
                function (response)
                {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            )
        }



    }
})();
```

Second Controller **verify-mobile.controller.js**

```
(function ()
{
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.pages.auth.verify-mobile',["app.pages.auth.login"])
        .controller('VerifyMobileController', VerifyMobileController);

    /** @ngInject */
    function VerifyMobileController(dataService)
    {
        var data = dataService.getData();

        alert(data);
    }
})();
```

Please somebody help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating common controller functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324202/creating-common-controller-functions)

Comment: No, That question is different. I want to create a service that will able to pass data between two controllers having different modules.

Comment: I'm removing the angular2 tag since this seems like an angular1 question. Tell me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: yes. you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not wrong. But I think you should make a module for your `dataService` and share it between others modules. You `dataService` don't really depends on your login module, so you can make it independant.

something like this :

```
  angular
    .module('app.services.shared')
    .factory('dataService', dataService);

 angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.login',["app.services.shared"])
 angular
    .module('app.pages.auth.verify-mobile',["app.services.shared"])
```

But it's subjective ...

Hope it's help.

**Update 1**

Exemple here [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/oPipdN?p=preview)

Comment: still, I got one error " Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addData' of undefined"

Comment: dataService seems to be undefined, did you check the order of your import ?

Comment: yeah. there is /app/core/services inside that I defined a service with module('app.core')  and importing with the same. Is it right ?

Comment: Yes, I think. Did you check, your dependencies injection in the controller you've got the error, you may change the name ?

Comment: Which name you are talking about ?

Comment: Your service name