# How to call a multiple controllers in single template in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
angular.module('test').controller('list', function($scope) {
    // Call entire test controller here
});

angular.module('test')
    .controller('getCustomers', function($scope) {
});
```

I need to implement this in order to access functions in the other controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating common controller functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324202/creating-common-controller-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend one controller to another by using the `$controller` service, something like:

```
angular.module('test')
    .controller('list', function($scope,$controller) {
        $controller('getCustomers', {$scope: $scope});
        $scope.getCustomersFn();
});
angular.module('test')
    .controller('getCustomers', function($scope) {
        $scope.getCustomersFn = function(){}
});
```

This is specially usefull if you want to create controller inheritance, but consider whether using a factory/provider is best suitable for your case, because it can be a bit hard to understand if you abuse it.