# conditional properties in angularJS Application between two controllers

Tags: angularjs

### In My Application I have two controllers .

Controller 1     | Controller 2

---

1. **From Controller 1** I am opening a menu on a button click and in a function     defined a property say,
   this.isTelephoneMenuOpen = true;

Result : I am getting menu opened With two option edit and Remove.

2.**From Controller 2** 
on click of edit I am opening a modal-overlay-  working fine.

**Issue :But not being able to hide the earlier opened menu.**

How to use this property in another controller to hide the menu after modal gets opened?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating common controller functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324202/creating-common-controller-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Define the property as `$rootScope` as every application has a single root scope.

**In Controller 1** - `$rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = true`.

**In Controller 2** - Set it to false after opening the menu       `$rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false`.

Comment: @lakshaya : Thanks Lakshya.
Initially,$rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false ----->In Controller 1

Then,
$rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = true ----->In Controller 1
Result: opens the menu

Need to make , $rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false----->In Controller 2

But Its taking false as intial value...so how to make it false again in controller 2 ?

Comment: u don't have to set `$rootScope.isTelephoneMenuOpen = false` as initial value. you should set it to false at the time  when your model is opened and the menu should hide.

Comment: @lakshya:In My Project , Rootscope is not working :(
Menu is not getting open when I put this property to Rootscope

Comment: have u defined $rootScope in your controller?

Comment: @lakshya: In First Controller : Getting the value true

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways is broadcast event, have a look at the $rootScope.$broadcast().

For example, in the second controller you can broadcast an event

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('hideMenu', {hide: true})
```

and then catch it in the first controller

```
$scope.$on('hideMenu', function (event, data) {
  //code for hiding menu
});
```