# Parent and child controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, separation-of-concerns

Having two controllers, parent and child.

```
<div ng-controller="firstCtrl as first">
   <div ng-controller="secondCtrl as second"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function() {
  this.func = function() {
    //some code
  };
});

app.controller('secondCtrl', function() {
  this.parent.func(some_data);//thats what I need to do   
});
```

Is it possible to do this without using a factory or `$scope.$parent`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18461263/can-an-angularjs-controller-inherit-from-another-controller-in-the-same-module

Comment: That is where factories / services are for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this without using factory or $scope.$parent?

No, you can't.

As a side note, I don't really like using `$scope.$parent`. in a big app, you can really loose the control of your app by imbricating such things.

If you would like to share a function between controllers, you may want to use a [`service`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11324202/creating-common-controller-functions) instead.

Comment: Can I call in html two functions like: first.func(),second,func() ?

Answer (score 0):

Inject $scope into your parent controller and in child controller as well, and save method of parent into $scope like following:

### Parent:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl','$scope',function(){
  $scope.yourFunctionName = function(some_data){
  //some code
  };
});
```

and in child do it like following to call parent controller method:

### Child

```
app.controller('secondCtrl', '$scope',function(){
  $scope.yourFunctionName(some_data);//thats what I need to do

  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although as mentioned a service/factory is probably better here but if you want another option you could use components. Example:

```
angular.module('app')
   .component('parent', {
       controller: function() {
            var $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.doStuff = function() {};
       },
       templateUrl: '/view.html'
   });

angular.module('app')
   .component('child', {
       require: {
           parent: '^parent'
       },
       controller: function() {
            var $ctrl = this;
            $ctrl.$onInit() = function() {
                $ctrl.parent.doStuff();
            };
       },
       templateUrl: '/view.html'
   });
```

Add the parent as to the components require then in the $onInit function you'll have access to any data/methods on it. Hope that helps.